# How can I make an image out of a k8s specific pod container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, images

I have made a pod, and it has only one container, I've been able to connect ot it by using `kubectl exec -it -c <container_name> <pod_name> bash`

And I've installed and done several stuff on it.

Now I wish to create an image out of that container to record all those changes in a single image.

I am using docker as the driver. And typically, if this container would have been just any other regular docker container (not managed by k8s), I would have just made a `docker commit <container_name>`

Is there a way to something similar but considering the container is managed inside a pod of k8s?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I wish to create an image out of that container to record all those changes in a single image.

That is generally the wrong way to go about it: you should create your image using a `Dockerfile`, and then deploy it to Kubernetes to test it. You should treat your running container as "read-only" and only makes changes by updating your Dockerfile (or similar) and re-building the image.

Doing things this way ensures that you are able to re-create the image, and allows you to use version control on the Dockerfile so that you have a record of what changes you made and why.

> Is there a way to something similar but considering the container is managed inside a pod of k8s?

The only way to create an image* from the running container would be to use `docker commit`. There is no Kubernetes mechanism for performing this action. You'll need to log into the Kubernetes node on which your container is running and run `docker commit` there, and then potentially `docker push` the image to a repository if you intend on running it elsewhere.

---

*: That's a bit of a simplification. E.g., you could use something like `tar` to export the filesystem, and once you have that there are various way to unpack it into an image.

Comment: Yeah I know dockerfile would be better, but I was just looking for a quick workarround to get all that I have done without having to do Dockerfile for saving time. It's not something that will be changing in the future, it was just a one-time thing. Either way, when you mention to run docker commit on the kubernetes node, to what would I commit to? the pod is not a container that I could commit right?

Comment: You said in your question that you're using the docker driver for Kubernetes. That means that each container in your pod is an actual Docker container. I don't use Docker in my k8s environments, but you should be able to run `docker ps` on the appropriate node and get a list of containers; from there you'll probably need to match up the container id with the pod somehow.

Comment: well I have made a deployment of 3 pods, each with 2 containers. I wen I run docker ps on the managing noe (I am using minikube so it's all on my local pc really) I get only 1 kubernetes container. And even if I delete the deployment and have no deployments & pods , that container is still there. Should I have seen 1 k8s container per pod-container there was?